# Lazy load google maps before constructing class in angular factory

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I have a module that uses google maps to make a map, get the users location and place a marker on the map where they are. I wanted a custom animated marker so I had to make a factory initializing a custom OverlayView Class. I also wanted the map loaded asynchronously so I created a factory like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59678/simple-async-google-maps-initializer-with-angularjs)
to handle loading google maps.

I can load the map fine by doing this:

```
initializer.gMapReady.then(function(){
    //call service method to make map
});
```

But I dont know how to use my initializer for my OverlayView factory that looks like this:

```
.factory('locMarker', function() {

    LocationMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView(); // This returns the error, google is not defined 

    function LocationMarker(opts) {
        this.setValues(opts);
    }

    LocationMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
           //
           // Code for drawing the marker on the map
           //
        }
    };
    return LocationMarker;
})
```

Whenever I load the page the map shows up fine but my custom marker never displays. I get a reference error, google is not defined, that points to the line `LocationMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();` If I don't lazy load google maps and just add the script to the index page everything runs fine.

Is there a way for me to call my maps initializer from within the locMarker factory so that google maps is loaded before it tries to construct the class?

**Update:**

As estus mentioned in the comments, I could use a resolver in the states/routes but I am trying to make this module not require that if possible.

Comment: Use route/state resolver. You can't postpone service factories/constructors without router.

Comment: @estus Sorry, I should have mentioned, I know that is an option but I am trying to make this module work without having to configure any kind of resolve in the states/routes. Do you think there is another approach?

Comment: No. Router is used exactly for that even if the app doesn't require much routing. Otherwise Angular bootstrap should be delayed.

Comment: @estus Ok. Thank you for your help